# Select from two tables with INNER JOIN not functioned as expect

Tags: php, mysql

I need a little help setting up my query. I'm simply trying to get the users from table `advertise_jobs` who have the same ID in the table `applicants` or in another meaning I need to get the users who have applied on a job from the `advertise_jobs` by the id.

this is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT applicants.*, advertise_jobs.*, uid 
FROM applicants 
INNER JOIN advertise_jobs 
 ON applicants.ads_id=advertise_jobs.id 
GROUP BY applicants.ads_id
```

it's not functioned as expect it gets other jobs that the users didn't apply to
how can I fix my query to be something like

```
select * from applicants and * from advertise_jobs where applicants.ads_id = uid
```

Comment: You're trying to get the users/applicants but you're grouping by `applicants.ads_id`?

Comment: Thanks @Alternatex so I try this `applicants.uid`

Comment: Any time you see DISTINCT and GROUP BY in the same sentence, something's probably gone wrong! ;-)

Comment: sorry I am confused and it's not working yet

Comment: In that case... If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
SELECT DISTINCT applicants.uid, advertise_jobs.ads_id
  FROM applicants,advertise_jobs
   WHERE applicants.uid=advertise_jobs.uid 
   GROUP BY applicants.ads_id
```